# Using Craft::import() to include external resource into the Craft Namespace

Tags: plugin-development, import

Looking at [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11828/include-a-php-resource-within-a-plugin), I suppose I am under the assumption that Craft::import() will take an alias, find the path, and import that class into the Craft namespace... which would be the benefit over simply using `require_once()`.

Currently I import with: 
`Craft::import('plugins.myplugin.resources.chargebee.lib.ChargeBee', true);`

Which works, however to use ChargeBee.php, I have to reference it from the global namespace. Not sure if this is the expected behaviour, but I would love to work within the Craft namespace if possible. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and import that class into the Craft namespace

Nope... it'll import that file, but will use whatever namespace the file is using (including global).

My guess is that the `ChargeBee.php` file has a `ChargeBee` class in it that lives in the global namespace, which is why you have to reference it there.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. So there is currently no good way to bring external resources into the Craft namespace? I suppose that makes sense now that I'm thinking about it...

Comment: And with that, what is the benefit of using `Craft::import()` over `require_once()`?